# insert template into template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have three templates, of which one is the main template temp_main.

```
<template id="temp_main">
    <div class="">          
        //rest of the form
        <div class="" id="add_or_remove_button">    
            <!-- remove or add button   -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="temp_add_button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add">
    <img src="../img/add-icon.png"/ alt="Add"></a>
</template>

<template id="temp_remove_button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove">
    <img src="../img/remove-icon.png"/>             
</template>
```

One of the two other ones should be inserted into the `<div id="add_or_remove_button">` depending on the case.

The main template I insert into a wrapper `div` by:

```
var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
var newInputLine = $("#temp_main").html();
var add_buttonHTML = $("#temp_add_button").html();  
var remove_buttonHTML = $("#temp_remove_button").html();    
$(wrapper).append(newInputLine);
```

How can I add either the add or the remove button to this template? I tried:

```
$("#temp_main").$("#add_or_remove_button").html(add_buttonHTML);
```

but that´s wrong and probably a bad solution

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).$ is not a function"

EDIT:
So it´s working. Is this a good practice?

```
 $(wrapper).append(newInputLine);
 $(".wrapper div:last-child #add_or_remove_button").append(add_buttonHTML);
```

Comment: "but that's wrong" - what does that mean? Anything not working with the given code?

Comment: `$('#temp_main').append(add_buttonHTML);`... ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the add_buttonHTML should be inserted to the ```div id="add_ore_remove_div"``` of ```div id="temp_main"```

Comment: @NicoHaase any experienced jquery developer will immediately tell you `$(..).$(..)` won't work.  That's why OP is here.  Kudos to OP for trying *something* and letting us know what they've tried.

Comment: Use `.find` to locate a sub element.  eg `$(wrapper).append(newInputLine).find("#add_or_remove_button").html(add_buttonHTML);` **NB** this (your entire concept and the line here) will only work if you only ever add 1 temp_main to your wrapper.   Otherwise you need to start using classes and `.appendTo` instead: `$(newInputLine).appendTo(wrapper).find(".add_or_remove_button").html(add_buttonHTML);`

Comment: Re edit:  `$(".wrapper div:last-child #add_or_remove_button")` implies that there will be multiple elements with the same ID.  This *will* cause you problems.  Your best solution is to remove `id=` from all code that will be repeated (ie all code *inside* your templates) and use classes.

Comment: So you answered your question in the question. The followup question on good practice will be too much a matter of an opinion for this site.